# html5 how to change position of image while user is scrolling down

Tags: javascript, css, html

How does a web developer obtain the variable when the client is scrolling up/down/sideways into a web browser? if i was to get that i wish to make a picture move slowly depending on how much the web scrollbar is moving, follow the URL to see what i mean: http://www.apple.com/macbook/

Here is what i have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      #top {
        background: blue;            
      }
      #p1 {
        margin-left: 50%;
        color: pink;
      } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top">
      <p id="p1">Adan's Website</p>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
      <img src="assets/pic.jpg" width="1280" height="720"/> <!-- your image goes here -->
    </div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but you should look into `parallax scrolling`. 
Couldn't find a good tutorial for it right now, but I think thats what you need.

Comment: yea the key word is parallax, researching as we speak, if i find answer il add it here

Answer (score 1):

using this parallax function, an image that's in front of the background will scroll along the users scroll, heres a great tutorial video on parallax step-by-step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D75WTf_Y738  and lastly here's the code:

```
 function parallax()
{
    var topdiv = document.getElementById('topdiv'); 
    topdiv.style.top = window.pageYOffset + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false);
```

topdiv = target image you want to move while user is scrolling. it's id belongs to a div element.

in order for this to work you must have a background image in the body that is *fixed.  then use div to call another image *the moving image in a div element (or possibly other ways), then add in this function and that's it, as for changing values, do some research because i just found this answer, i havent mastered all it's mechanics.